# How to parameterize part of filename and output that to a column in azure data factory?

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-data-factory

I have read the docs about parameterizing, my table needs only the month name from the file name to be extracted and output that to a column? how can i do this? without creating external file format?( i tried using parameters but i am not clear on this)

Can you please explain in detail?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Monsta, If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According my experience,  we can't parameterize part of filename and output that to a column in azure data factory.

[Get metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) is the only activity which Data Factory provides for us to get the filename.

[image]

We can pass the filename as parameter to specify the new file or create a new filename with expression.

There is no ways can transfer the filename as a column.

Hope this helps.